# If the past participle of "say" is "said", and "lay" is "laid", why the one of "stay" is not "staid"?

Tags: verbs, past-participles, irregular-verbs

I know about the word "staid". Does the past participle of "stay" is "stayed" to avoid confusion with this word?

Or the "staid" past participle existed at some time, but it was supplanted by "stayed", like "dreamed" is replacing "dreamt"?

Comment: Because it's English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use two irregularly spelled words as a basis for figuring out (or for explaining) the spelling of other words. That's a recipe for confusion. "Stayed" is the regular, expected spelling for the past participle and past tense of "stay"; likewise, the past participles of *bay, pray, play, array, delay, decay, spray, display, sway* end in *-ayed* and not in *-aid.* They are not spelled with *-ayed* to avoid confusion with other words; they are spelled with *-ayed* because most past participles are spelled by adding *-ed* to the base form of the word.

The past participle of the verb *stay* was spelled many different ways in the past. The Oxford English Dictionary gives the following list:

> ME–17 stayd, 15 Scottish stayit, stayet, steyit, 15–16 stayde, staied, staide, 15–18 staid, 15– stayed.

Related question: [Why is "say" spelled differently for "said" and "says"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371510)

Comment: And of course, _staid_ is still used, but only as an adjective (originally the past participle of _stay_), similar to the partially complementary distribution of _borne_ and _born_.

Comment: I try to find patterns with the irregular verbs forms, but I did not think of all the regular ones you are evocating. So I agree that was a bit of a hasteful question from myself. Thanks for the detailed answer however.